# Requesting screen recording and accessibility approvals from Node.js command line executables

Tags: javascript, node.js, objective-c, macos, npm

I'm a Mac developer mostly using Objective-C and never used Node.js before. Recently I need to write Mac native CLI (the **Helper**) that will be launched from another executable written using Node.js, built with `pkg` and run as an agent (the **Agent**).

**Problem #1**

The `Helper` needs to do some screen capture and controls the keyboard and microphone from time to time. In order to do so, the `Agent` has to be approved in the `System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy`. Originally I thought it is the `Helper` that has to be approved, but it turns out to be the `Agent`, likely because `Agent` is launching `Helper`.

**Problem #2**

Because the `Agent/Helper` pair are going to be installed in lab environment (local and remote), it is desirable that all the approval process done at the install time, instead of prompting the user at the time the application is being used. The main reason for this is because the user running the application is a `Standard user` and doesn't know `Admin password`.

So far I've tried two approaches to try solve my problems.

**First approach**

Call the `Agent` from a post install script and pass a special argument such that it will call the Helper to trigger the prompt (ie. by calling `CGRequestScreenCaptureAccess()` and `+ (void)requestAccessForMediaType:(AVMediaType)mediaType completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL granted))handler`.
Since the Helper is written in Objective-C, it can have embedded Info.plist where I can add the entitlements.

The issue with this approach is, I only see the first request dialog (`Agent` would like to record this computer's screen) and not the subsequent requests for `Accessibility` and `Microphone`.

```
        // Request for accessibility approval
        NSDictionary *options = @{(id)CFBridgingRelease(kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt): @YES};
        BOOL accessibilityEnabled = AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions((CFDictionaryRef)options);
        if (!accessibilityEnabled)
        {
            NSString *urlString = @"x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Accessibility";
            [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        }

        // Request for screen capture approval
        if (@available(macOS 10.15, *))
        {
            bool granted = CGPreflightScreenCaptureAccess();
            if (!granted)
            {
                granted = CGRequestScreenCaptureAccess();
                if (granted)
                {
                    os_log_info(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "Screen capture access granted");
                }
                else
                {
                    os_log_info(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "Screen capture access has been denied");
                }
            }
        }
        
        // Request for microphone approval
        if (@available(macOS 10.14, *))
        {
            AVAuthorizationStatus status = [AVCaptureDevice authorizationStatusForMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
            switch (status)
            {
                case AVAuthorizationStatusAuthorized:
                {
                    os_log_info(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "Microphone access has been previously granted");
                    break;
                }
                case AVAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
                {
                    os_log_info(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "Attempting to request approval for Microphone");
                    [AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo completionHandler:^(BOOL granted) {
                        if (granted)
                        {
                            os_log_info(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "Microphone access granted");
                        }
                    }];
                    break;
                }
                case AVAuthorizationStatusDenied:
                {
                    os_log_info(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "Microphone access has been previously denied");
                }
                case AVAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
                {
                    os_log_info(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "User cannot grant Microphone access due to restrictions");
                }
            }
        }
```

**Second approach**

Similar to first approach but instead of calling the Helper, make the `Agent` perform all the requests using  `node-mac-permissions`. The issue with this second approach is, I need to embed `Info.plist` to the `Agent` to add the `entitlements` but I don't know how to do so using `pkg` or other `Node.js` modules.

**My question is**

Are there better ways to process all the requests in `Node.js`, perhaps using different modules and not having to use entitlements?

Comment: Ask one question at a time.

Comment: @OlSen Thanks for your comment. I can't really do that because the end user (in this case the lab users) are Standard users and don't know Admin's password, so they can't unlock System Preferences -> Security & Privacy pane. My goal is to handle all the approval requests during installation when the the computer admin can unlock it.

Comment: I was thinking about security impact on my approach too. But what you said about Admin permission would allow users to set their own is interesting, I have to try that. Thanks for the info on privacy too.

Comment: Just differentiate between setting permissions and allowing to use given permissions. One part ends up in the system-settings the other appears at users action with the dialog.